# Meteor, display/sort value by boolean

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, collections, semantic-ui

I'm working on a table in Meteor template, where the is a boolean field "emergency"
I would like to display in the table the cells where there is the "emergency" flag FIRST, and then the others ...

How can I do that please ?

here is the find, I tried to sort(), find and sort inside but It doesn't work .. :/

```
Template.actionsList.helpers({
    actions: function() {
        return Actions.find();
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance :)

---

I get the error: Exception in template helper: TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of null

My code is:

```
Session.set('emergency', false);
Template.actionForm.onRendered(function () {
    var $elem = this.$('.emergency');
    $elem.checkbox('set ' + (Session.get('emergency') ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'));
    $elem.checkbox({
            onChange: function () {
              Session.set('emergency', !Session.get('emergency'));
            }
    });
});

Template.actionForm.events({
    'submit .new-action': function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var emergency = Session.get('emergency');
    ...
       Actions.insert({
        emergency: emergency
    ....
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Sorry for the no-editing post ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use underscore's **[`sortBy()`](http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy)** method to sort on objects checking if the 'emergency' field exists via the **[`hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)** native method:

```
Template.actionsList.helpers({
    actions: function() {
        var actions = Actions.find().fetch();
        return _.sortBy(actions, function (a) { return !a.hasOwnProperty('emergency'); });
    }
});
```

Check the demo below.

```js
var actions = [
 {
  "_id" : "ukn9MLo3hRYEpCCty",    
  "field" : "foo"
 },
 {
  "_id" : "ukn9MLo3hRYEpCCty",    
  "field" : "bar",
  "emergency": true
 },
 {
  "_id" : "WMHWxeymY4ATWLXjz",    
  "field" : "abc",
  "emergency": false
 },
 {
  "_id" : "5SXRXraariyhRQACe",    
  "field" : "xyz"   
 }
];

var result = _.sortBy(actions, function (a) { return !a.hasOwnProperty('emergency'); });

pre.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result, undefined, 4);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.7.0/underscore-min.js"></script>
<pre id="pre"></pre>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. It doesn't work, I get a message: Exception in template helper: TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of null. It's really weird cause when I log my result filed, it false or true, so boolean ... I'm writing the code on an answer post .

Comment: @chridam `Actions.find();` returns a cursor and not an array. Use `Actions.find().fetch();` instead.

Comment: @MatthiasEckhart Thanks!

Comment: @chridam: Thanks but doesn't work. I understand your code and affect it to my code, but it seems to not do anything ... :/ When I display the result of my fetch, I have all fields displayed like if the sort didn't do anything ... (so in the creation order) I answer to the question to display more code. Thanks for helping